# How to transpose a steam of m:n data into a n:m table?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say we collect statistics for car model / tire model compatibility. The input stream lists the car model as key and the compatible tire models as value:

*car-tire-topic*:

```
car1 -> [tire1, tire2, tire3]
car2 -> [tire2, tire4]
```

The desired end result is a table with the tire model as key, and the number of car models which are compatible with that tire:

*tire-count-table*:

```
tire1 -> 1
tire2 -> 2
tire3 -> 1
tire4 -> 1
```

Tire models become discontinued sometimes. They are then removed from the compatibility list:

*car-tire-topic*:

```
car1 -> [tire2, tire3]
```

('tire1' got removed).
On the other hand new tire models enter the market and are added to the compatibility list:

*car-tire-topic*:

```
car1 -> [tire2, tire3, tire5]
```

**How can I achieve this transformation using Kafka Streams DSL?**

**My approach #1**
In a `carTireStream.flatTransform()` I retrieve the old tire compatibility list from `tire-car-table` state store. For each tire model missing in the new value (got deleted) I emit a record with a composite key:

```
{carId, tireId} -> null
```

For each tire model missing in old list (got added) I emit a

```
{carId, tireId} -> 1
```

record. This stream is then aggregated by key to a `car-tire-diff-table`. This table contains only valid car / tire model combinations. All discontinued car/tire combinations get removed by the `null` value records.

After that, this table is grouped by tire model (by retrieving the tire model from the composite key). The group aggregator and subtractor functions create lists adding/removing the car model from/to the list of car models. The result is the `tire-car-table`:

```
tire2 -> [car1, car2]
tire3 -> [car1]
tire4 -> [car2]
tire5 -> [car1]
```

(tire1 got removed, remember?)

The last step is easy. I apply a `.mapValues()` on this table, and emit the length of the list.

This approach has sevaral downsides:

- It is not pure Stream DSL.
- I have to access the `tire-car-table` state store before it got introduced declaratively.
- It requires a intermediate `car-tire-diff-table`.
- The values of the `car-tire-diff-table` are only used to map the create / delete operations (`1` / `null`).

**My approach #2**
Using the processor API I can avoid the intemediate table and the weird create/delete tracking values.

A processor consumes the `car-tire-topic`. It reads the old value from the `car-tire-table` and stores the new value into the `car-tire-table` (thus updating it). Having the old and the new tire compatibility list in one place: for each added tire model, it reads from the `tire-car-table`, adds the car model to the list, and writes back the value; for each deleted tire model, it reads from the `tire-car-table`, removes the car model, and writes the updated list back.

Drawbacks of this approach:

- The `tire-car-table` has to be a global table. There is now way I could create an algorithm, which could map any possible car/tire combination in to one partition, while still having multiple partitions.
- The processor contains many operations.
- I see no way how I can implement the last count step using Stream DSL. I can create a state store instance for `tire-car-tabble` using `StreamsBuilder.addStateStore()`, but I found no way to create a `KTable` instance from that.

Limitation: this is a generalization of the original problem. I cannot work around the problem by changing what the source topic contains. Or by adding a 'tire got removed from the marked' stream and simply delete the tire record from the `tire-car-table`.

The whole thing would be easier, if the `KTable` api would expose some kind of an update handler, which would receive the old and the new value.

Can some one come up with a more elegant approach to solve the problem than mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the full transposed mapping, I don't think you can do much better than approach #1. As you pointed out you have two stateful steps with different keys, so you must do the operation in at least two steps to support multiple partitions.

If all you want is the final count, you could `flatTransform` your original `carTireStream` stream into
either `tireId -> 1` for a new tire entry or `tireId -> -1` for a tire entry that was removed (using your `tire-car-table` state store) then...

```
tireDeltaStream
  .groupByKey()
  .reduce((oldCount, delta) -> oldCount + delta)
```

You now have a table with the latest count of cars per tire which you can query (if you give it a name) or write out to a stream.

If you want to do the whole thing using the high level DSL, the only way I could think of would be to replace the `flatTransform` call with an `aggregate` on the `carTireStream` stream retaining the latest list of tires *and* a list of the deltas then `flatMap` to extract the deltas.

For instance the following message on the `carTireStream` topic

```
car1 -> [tire1, tire2, tire3]
```

would be transformed by the aggregate into...

```
car1 -> ([tire1, tire2, tire3], [tire1 -> 1, tire2 -> 1, tire3 -> 1])
```

which after a `flatMap` that extracted the deltas would be...

```
tire1 -> 1
tire2 -> 1
tire3 -> 1
```

Then, the following message on the `carTireStream` topic

```
car1 -> [tire2, tire3, tire5]
```

would be transformed by the aggregate into...

```
car1 -> ([tire2, tire3, tire5], [tire1 -> -1, tire5 -> 1])
```

which after a flatMap would be...

```
tire1 -> -1
tire5 -> 1
```

That approach would be a lot cleaner if the aggregate method had a mechanism to emit different value(s) than the current value of the internal state.
In that case you would just store the latest list of tire ids and emit the `tireId -> delta` values removing the need to store the extra state and have an extra `flatMap` step.